# Add a column based on a condition from other columns

Tags: r

I have this table and I would like to add the colum "New column" based on a condition. The condition is that when in the column 3, we have "Peter", then in the "New col" I want to have the result of the col2. This value would be the same for the same ID. In the "New Col", you can see the desire result.

```
ID  Col2    Col3    New Col
1   B   Peter   B
1   A   Matt    B
2   B   Peter   B
2   B   Matt    B
2   A   Matt    B
3   C   Peter   C
```

This is what I have.

```
for (j in 2:(j-1)){
  if (df$Col3[j] == "Peter"){
    df$Newcol[j] = df$Col2[j]
  } else {
    df$Newcol[j] = df$Newcol[j-1]  
  }
}
```

But instead of getting the rigth values, I get numbers "6" and "9".

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot

Comment: and what if not "Peter" ? Please edit your question!

Comment: I assume you are grouping by 'ID` and expecting `Col2` values corresponding to "Peter" in each group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[,new:= if(any(Col3 == "Peter")) Col2[which(Col3 == "Peter")] else NA, by = ID]

#   ID Col2  Col3 new
#1:  1    B Peter   B
#2:  1    A  Matt   B
#3:  2    B Peter   B
#4:  2    B  Matt   B
#5:  2    A  Matt   B
#6:  3    C Peter   C
```

Using base R `lapply`

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(split(data, data$ID), 
        function(x){ if(any(x$Col3 == "Peter")){ 
        x$new = x$Col2[which(x$Col3 == "Peter")]; 
        x}}))

#    ID Col2  Col3 new
#1.1  1    B Peter   B
#1.2  1    A  Matt   B
#2.3  2    B Peter   B
#2.4  2    B  Matt   B
#2.5  2    A  Matt   B
#3    3    C Peter   C
```

**data**

```
data = structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Col2 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    Col3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Matt", 
    "Peter"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Col2", "Col3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```